# Array of object. Limit to an X amount of elements that a specific property can have as max

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with nested arrays. That looks like the following

```
[
{
 type: 'type',
 props: {
  latitude: 100,
  items: [
   {type: 'item1' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item2' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item3' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item4' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item5' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
  ]
 }
},
{
 type: 'type2',
 props: {
  latitude: 150,
  items: [
   {type: 'item1' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item2' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item4' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item5' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
  ]
 }
},
...
]
```

Now I want this array to have [x].props.items <= 3 elements
I dont care about the order, I basically want to lets say keep the first 3 elements

resulting in

```
[
{
 type: 'type',
 props: {
  latitude: 100,
  items: [
   {type: 'item1' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item2' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item3' , elements: '10', utilities: '100}
  ]
 }
},
{
 type: 'type2',
 props: {
  latitude: 150,
  items: [
   {type: 'item1' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item2' , elements: '10', utilities: '100},
   {type: 'item4' , elements: '10', utilities: '100}
  ]
 }
},
...
]
```

I have tried doing

```
let newArr = arr.map(i => i.map(j => j.props.items.slice(0,3)))
```

But I dont think im heading in the right direction

Comment: Do you want to use map because you need to return a new array or anything else can be accepted?

Comment: @briosheje im trying to retun the same array of objects, but with max 3 elements in props.items in every object in the array

Comment: So that's irrelevant. You're not that far from the solution, a working approach based on your code is the following: https://jsfiddle.net/amg84v6d/ although I won't use map for this, but a simple forEach.